# stickykit.js causes overlapping with bootstrap columns on some monitors

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, jquery-plugins, sticky

I'm experiencing some problems with columns overlapping each other when I use stickykit.js,

[mikewhitecreative.com/gallery%20page.html](http://mikewhitecreative.com/gallery%20page.html)

This is my portfolio I'm working on. When viewed on my monitor, everything is fine. Images on the left scroll, while the text is in a fixed position.

[image: image description]

But when I look at it on my laptop, the two column sections seem to overlap.

[image: image description]

The images are set to "col-md-6" and the text is "col-md-6", Changing the text to "col-md-offset-1 col-md-5" Fixes the issue for my laptop, but subsequently causes the same issue on my monitor.

Laptop screen dimensions: 1280 x 720

Monitor screen dimensions: 1920 x 1080

JSfiddle containing the html portion and stickykit code in the comments, i can't upload more than 2 links.

Comment: Please add your html and js code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/7xwLoq2n/

Should i upload the bootstrap.js?